# Clearing app settings related to file type

Tags: applications, files

I'm trying to open a file written in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), with the extension `.R`.

While I alternately used [Turbo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maskyn.fileeditor&hl=en) and another application to edit `.R` and other text files, at some point, I set as the default app to open `.R` files as an app I deleted and no longer use.

When I try to open a `.R` file, say, from email, I receive the message `You don't have an app that can open this file . . .`. But, I previously opened `.R. files with Turbo Editor.

Is there a way to clear app settings related to file types? Is there another setting I may be missing?

Comment: What is the file type of the file written in R?

Comment: Not sure--I wrote it in a text editor (TextWrangler) but saved it with the extension `.R`.